# Check the existence of folder on server and change the content if not

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i need to check on AngularJS exists or not the folder on server, if yes - show standard page, if not - change div's content to another html code.

How to check exist the folder or not?

Comment: You cannot do that with frontend JavaScript. You would need to do that in your backend code.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if angular loaded on the page with javascript:

```
if(typeof angular == 'undefined') {
    ....
}
```